# Why isn't getElementById() available on Elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, compatibility, specifications

Most DOM query methods are available on both `Document`s and `Element`s. For example,

```
console.assert(
  document.getElementsByTagName   && document.body.getElementsByTagName &&
  document.getElementsByClassName && document.body.getElementsByClassName &&
  document.querySelector          && document.body.querySelector &&
  document.querySelectorAll       && document.body.querySelectorAll
);
```

However, `getElementById` is only available on `Document`:

```
console.assert(document.getElementById);
console.assert(document.body.getElementById == undefined);
```

Why is this so?

---

The WHATWG DOM Living Standard [tells us that](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nonelementparentnode):

> Web compatibility prevents the `getElementById()` method from being exposed on elements

The W3C DOM4 Recommendation [is a bit more specific](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#interface-nonelementparentnode):

> The `getElementById()` method is not on elements for compatibility with older versions of jQuery. If a time comes where that version of jQuery has disappeared, we might be able to support it.

However, I still have a hard time understanding what the issue could be. How could the presence of this methods adversely affect the behaviour of jQuery or other libraries?

I've tried looking through old versions of jQuery (such as [1.0.0](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.0.js) and [1.7.0](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.0.js)) to see if any of their use of `getElementById` hints at why this may have been a problem. I see that `getElementById` used to be buggy in some older browsers, but they detect that and fall back to a reliable manual implementation instead. I don't see anywhere that it could be called on an element and cause a bug. Where does this compatibility concern come from?

Comment: Because id values must be unique throughout the entire document, what would be the point?

Comment: I can't give you a definitive answer, but I would surmise it's because `id` attributes should be unique within the DOM. As such it does not matter at what level you perform the `getElementById()` call, hence they only implemented it on the `document`.

Comment: There may only be only one element, but I may only be interested in it if it exists in a particular subtree of the document.

Comment: You can use `.querySelector()` to determine that.

Comment: @Pointy I have quoted both specifications' compatibility concerns, so telling me it's because it's pointless seems incorrect.

Comment: I have no idea how or why an old version of jQuery would be a concern to the spec committee.

Comment: @Pointy: Because introducing `Element#getElementById` breaks existing websites that use that version of jQuery, apparently widely deployed at least in 2013.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `git blame` on https://github.com/w3c/dom’s master branch points to:

> commit [f71d7de304e1ee25573279157dd6ce1c2aa2c4f2](https://github.com/w3c/dom/commit/f71d7de304e1ee25573279157dd6ce1c2aa2c4f2)
>   Author:     Anne van Kesteren 
>   AuthorDate: Tue Nov 26 13:53:41 2013 +0000
>   Commit:     Anne van Kesteren <annevk@annevk.nl>
>   CommitDate: Tue Nov 26 13:53:41 2013 +0000
>
> Remove getElementById from Element. https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=23860

and the linked bug describes how jQuery 1.2.5 + 1.2.6 (1.2.x?) are affected:

> jQuery 1.2.5 assumes that any node it found in the DOM that has a "getElementById" property is a Document node.  See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=933193#c17

Comment: Jquery should have something else to check if the object is a Document node.

Comment: @RaymondPeng: It does now, but websites don’t all upgrade. Mistakes last a long time when popular software makes them.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said in the comments, element IDs are supposed to be unique. There would be no need to have a `getElementById` method on an element.

According to [MDN's article on `getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById#Usage_notes):

> Because ID values must be unique throughout the entire document, there is no need for "local" versions of the function.

The same is also true of [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)

Comment: But getElementsByName is only available on `document`, not elements. I believe the original intention was that names were unique and used the way we use IDs now. That would explain some of the browser bugs that older versions of jQuery worked around

Answer (score -4):

Having all your ids unique will really make your life easier.